# Pytorch: accessing a subtensor using lists of indices

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, matrix-indexing, tensor-indexing

I have a pair of tensors `S` and `T` of dimensions `(s1,...,sm)` and `(t1,...,tn)` with `si < ti`. I want to specify a list of indices in each dimensions of `T` to "embed" `S` in `T`. If `I1` is a list of `s1` indices in `(0,1,...,t1)` and likewise for `I2` up to `In`, I would like to do something like 
`T.select(I1,...,In)=S`
that will have the effect that now `T` has entries equal to the entries of `S` over the indices `(I1,...,In)`.
for example

```
`S=
[[1,1],
[1,1]]

T=
[[0,0,0],
[0,0,0],
[0,0,0]]

T.select([0,2],[0,2])=S

T=
[[1,0,1],
[0,0,0],
[1,0,1]]`
```

Comment: why are we not "filling in" for the 2nd row of `T`? where is this info encoded?

Answer (score 4):

If you're flexible with using NumPy *only for the indices part*, then here's one approach by constructing an open mesh using [**`numpy.ix_()`**](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) and using this mesh to fill-in the values from the tensor `S`. If this is not acceptable, then you can use [**`torch.meshgrid()`**](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.meshgrid.html)

Below is an illustration of both approaches with descriptions interspersed in comments.

```
# input tensors to work with
In [174]: T 
Out[174]: 
tensor([[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]])

# I'm using unique tensor just for clarity; But any tensor should work.
In [175]: S 
Out[175]: 
tensor([[10, 11],
        [12, 13]])

# indices where we want the values from `S` to be filled in, along both dimensions
In [176]: idxs = [[0,2], [0,2]]
```

---

Now we will leverage [`np.ix_()`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) or [`torch.meshgrid()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.meshgrid.html) to generate an open mesh by passing in the indices:

```
# mesh using `np.ix_`
In [177]: mesh = np.ix_(*idxs)

# as an alternative, we can use `torch.meshgrid()` 
In [191]: mesh = torch.meshgrid([torch.tensor(lst) for lst in idxs])

# replace the values from tensor `S` using basic indexing
In [178]: T[mesh] = S 

# sanity check!
In [179]: T 
Out[179]:
tensor([[10,  0, 11],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [12,  0, 13]])
```